# vba code - Replace text in html email without breaking formatting

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to replace specific text in an email (skype meeting invite) with a custom piece of text that is a URL. I can do this fine for plain text via a vba macro in outlook click to run (2016/2019), but if I run the below against the expected html email that the meetings create it breaks the formatting completely.

```
Sub ChangeS4bMeeting()
Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.body = Replace(Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.body, "Conference ID: ", "https://linkhere")
End Sub
```

It ends up replacing the text correctly and adding what follows that space after the colon to the replaced text as the URL, but formatting of the whole invite email breaks.

I have tried using "HTMLBody" value instead of "body" value but this fails to run at all as it breaks on that line. Any ideas? Would it also be possible to have this run automatically when I selected New Items > Skype Meeting in outlook rather than running the macro manually (or have the macro include the creation of a skype meeting directly)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that the content placed in the HTMLBody is properly formatted and that any such text is placed between the  and  tags in the HTMLBody.

For more information, please see the following link:[Find and Replace as a VBA Macro](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1f8f1680-61ec-4f78-aea4-9712abc5ccfd/find-and-replace-as-a-vba-macro?forum=outlookdev)

You can create custom rules that execute scripts to implement specific conditions for executing the script.

please see the following link: [Create a Custom Rule executing a Script](https://superuser.com/questions/464000/how-to-replace-text-in-the-body-of-an-incoming-message-with-a-hyperlink-in-outlo)